# Installing cx_oracle 5.2 in python 3.4.3 fails

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g

I'm trying to install cx_oracle in my python 3.4.3 on CentOS via pip, but it fails.

```
$ sudo pip3.4 install cx_oracle
Collecting cx-oracle
  Using cached cx_Oracle-5.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-m0e47l0_/cx-oracle/setup.py", line 168, in <module>
        instantClientRPMLib = FindInstantClientRPMLib()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-m0e47l0_/cx-oracle/setup.py", line 130, in FindInstantClientRPMLib
        versions.sort(key = lambda x: [int(s) for s in x.split(".")])
      File "/tmp/pip-build-m0e47l0_/cx-oracle/setup.py", line 130, in <lambda>
        versions.sort(key = lambda x: [int(s) for s in x.split(".")])
      File "/tmp/pip-build-m0e47l0_/cx-oracle/setup.py", line 130, in <listcomp>
        versions.sort(key = lambda x: [int(s) for s in x.split(".")])
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2_encryption_required'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-m0e47l0_/cx-oracle
```

Any idea?

Setuptools is already up-to-date:

```
$ sudo pip3.4 install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Oracle client is installed and happily used from PHP and others

```
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was caused by having a '/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/11.2_encryption_required' folder with an Oracle client where encryption was mandated.
Unfortunately in Oracle client you need to have a separate client if you want to use encryption for some of the connections you make and not for some of the other ones.

It seems that the cx_oracle installes's FindInstantClientRPMLib wasn't prepared to see any non-numerical values, so it failed on the "encryption_required" part.

Temporarily I have renamed the folder and then the installer error did go away.